# PHP/SQL - How to count saturdays in each month?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, count

I have two MySQL tables, called "accounts" and "events".

**Accounts**

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pete |
| 2 | Josh |
| 3 | Harry |

**Events**

| ID | date | account_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-09 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-09-25 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-10-23 | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-11-06 | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-10-13 | 1 |
| 6 | 2021-11-17 | 2 |
| 7 | 2021-11-06 | 3 |
| 8 | 2021-12-04 | 3 |

The account_id in the events table is linked to the id in the accounts table.

My question is: which query can I use to count saturdays in each month (date YYYY-mm-dd format) for each unique user in the accounts table? So I get the next result:

| Name | September | October | November | December |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Josh | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Pete | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Harry | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I've tried many queries (with i.e. the (inner) JOIN, DISTINCT and GROUP BY keywords) but I don't get the exact result. Can you please help me?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use DAYOFWEEK function and GROUP BY MONTH

```
SELECT 
    account_id,
    MONTH(date), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM Events 
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date) = 7
GROUP BY account_id, MONTH(date);
```

[SQL Fiddle here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=0bffd649efc0a72adb5cea605fe1e550&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

and when you can use PIVOT on received table like:

```
WITH res AS (
  SELECT 
      account_id,
      MONTH(date) mnth, 
      COUNT(*) cnt
  FROM Events 
  WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date) = 7
  GROUP BY account_id, MONTH(date)
) SELECT 
    account_id,
    name,
    SUM(mnth=1) Januar,
    -- 
    SUM(mnth=9) September,
    SUM(mnth=10) October,
    SUM(mnth=11) November,
    SUM(mnth=12) December
FROM res
JOIN Accounts ON Accounts.id = account_id
GROUP BY account_id, name;
```

[SQL Pivot Fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=8222ec48dfa086d796bbcbb93e37fc72&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)